# core 2.1 signalR successfully connecting but client is null

Tags: c#, signalr, ionic3

I am attempting to use signalR in the new dotnet core2.1.  I have my C# server set up and an ionic 3 app ready as the client.  I got as far as making a successful websocket connection between them.  When I try to use a SendAsync from the server to the client though, the client shows as null even though a successful connection was made.
I've done some testing and even tried using the OnConnectedAsync override to see what was happening.  It does trigger but the context.user.identity.name is empty and the client still comes up null.

In the browser log:

```
Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:xxxx/myHub
```

in my Hub

```
public async Task Send(string message)
{
  await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", message);
}
```

in the controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewBuild()
{
  await myHub.Send("New Build Completed.");
  return Ok();
}
```

in my startup

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
          builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials();
        }));

  services.AddSignalR();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

  app.UseSignalR(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapHub<myHub>("myHub");
  });
```

and in ionic

```
 hubConnection: HubConnection;
this.hubConnection =  new HubConnection('http://localhost:xxxx/myHub', {
  transport: TransportType.WebSockets
});
this.hubConnection.on("SendMessage", () => {
  this.InitTodayBuilds();
});

this.hubConnection.start().catch(() => console.error);
```

As I said, it seems to be connecting just fine.  But when the Send method gets called it gets a null exception.

Am I missing something stupid here?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. I  Injected the IHubContext into my hub class  to call the client side methods for the server side.

```
public class ChangeRequest: Hub, ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }
    protected IHubContext<ChangeRequest> _context;
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public ChangeRequest(IHubContext<ChangeRequest> context)
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("getMessage", string.Format("User {0}: {1}", AbpSession.UserId, message));
    }

    }
```

Comment: How did you inject IHubContext?